# clustering users based on their likes using machine learning in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, dataset, cluster-analysis

user id and likes as follows

1. milk,coffee,tea,sugar
2. curd,salt,sugar
3. milk,sugar,tea
4. curd,rice

I want to cluster users based on user's likes

Comment: I am fetching likes from social media.. i don't know what is user likes. based on kmeans text clustering i want to do but I am not getting how to do!

Answer (score -1):

you can follow this approach

convert the user's preferences to vectors, which each index correspond to some product and the value is 1 if the user like it or o otherwise, e.g

```
user 1 -> [1,1,1,1,0,0]
user 2 -> [0,0,0,1,1,1]
...
```

now you can easily use a KNN model with Euclidian distance, or use some other similarity method, you can use the most basic and easy [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) lib of clustering implementation

with more details such as provided code, output, logic and etc... I can be more case specific

Comment: m fetching likes from social media.. i don't know what is user likes. based on kmeans text clustering i want to do but i can't

Comment: @ManishKammar just follow those steps, where are you stuck? if you will provide a code it'll be more easy for me and others to help you